# How can I control UIImage size in UIPastboard?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, uipasteboard

I am copying an image to pasteboard the following way:

```
let image = UIImage(named: "my_image")
UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard().image = image
```

When I paste the following image into an iMessage it looks like the image size isn't taken into account. The image pasted is larger then the actual image and it is also pixelated (it doesn't look sharp).

The size of the image can be controlled in pasteboard in any way?

Comment: By larger, what do you mean? Where is the image coming from originally? Larger than what?

Comment: The image comes from xcassets. Larger than the image actual size in xcassets.

Comment: Filesize or dimensions?

Comment: So it's an @2x image?

Comment: @2x. I tested with 133x133 and 40x40 and the resulting pasted image appears larger and pixelated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I used an image with a width of 480 pixels and empty space on the sides, then I got the result I wanted: smaller and clear image(not pixelated like before).

When I used an image that had a small overall width the image looked pixelated. I don't know why is this, maybe is related to iMessage how it displays an image from pasteboard.